# How to convert a text with form 1'234'567.00 into a number in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, conversion

I would like to convert a text (type 2) with form 1'234'567.00 into a number (type 1) in Excel.
Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Which Excel version? And what have you tried already?

Comment: What about just replace (Ctrl+H) '  with empty string (and . with , if need)?

Comment: You could search and replace, or a string function, to remove the non-numeric characters. I don't think there is a way to tell Excel to ignore the apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like a formula approach, rather than operating on them by hand (or macro), the following will do nicely:

```
=NUMBERVALUE(A1,  ".",  "'")
```

`NUMBERVALUE`'s sole purpose is doing this. Its output is not just recognizable as a number by Excel, but rather an actual number.

One can use other formulas, but they all would basically operate on the strings as strings, then use a function like `N` or `VALUE` to convert the resulting strings to numbers. `NUMBERVALUE` does it "in one" as they used to say.

As to which approach to take, operating on the data IN PLACE has good reasons behind it and depending upon your circumstances, could be your only choice, boss-wise, even though not Excel-wise. Using a formula approach is desirable in other circumstances. It can be done in place, close to that, that is, and then, if you wish to replace the data with the number version, copied and pasted over it.

Another way one can use a formulaic approach, though way less common, would be to use your formula approach in the later on formulas that refer to it:  when they go to this data, you wouldn't put, say, `A34`, but rather `NUMBERVALUE(A34,  ".",  "'")`, into those later on formulas. You'd really only do this if not permitted to change this part of the spreadsheet. Even if you could only add a helper column or helper sheet to do this, and have those later on formulas refer to it, that'd be easier, probably.

So consider your needs, including those outside Excel itself, and pick an approach, either change-in-place, or formula=to-convert and then probably copy and paste|special.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Are the hyphens (**'**) thousands separators? If so, there are a few options:

- Search and replace hyphens with *nothing*, then convert the column type from text to numeric.
- Search and replace hyphens with *a standard thousands separator* such as comma (**,**), used in regions where a decimal place is indicated with period (**.** AKA *full stop*). Then convert the column type from text to numeric; Excel should "understand" that usage in conversion.
- Easiest: just [change the thousands separator in Excel to hyphen](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e). All texts thus formatted can be changed to numeric **and vice versa**, to recover the original format.